# Flask App not working via PyCharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I have been developing flask apps for some time now but when I switched to PyCharm, the basic app is also not working via PyCharm but otherwise it works fine :

app.py :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

import views

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

views.py :

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Here is the o/p:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2017 21:48:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2017 21:49:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

So basically it doesn't report any error but I cannot access the app as it gives "page not found" error. Any idea why? Also, it gives warning about "import views" statement saying it is an unused import.

If I add contents of views.py in app.py then it works via PyCharm.. But I want to modularize it.

Edit:

I found this now - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages but again do not know how and why to run setup.py file from pycharm.. :-(

Comment: is your app.py and view.py under the same directory?

Comment: if it is try `from . import app` under views.py

Comment: Yes it is under same dir.. will try that.. thanks

Comment: Simply we can say, the import is incorrect. Something unwanted is getting imported.

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO It didn't resolve the issue.. It started giving error on that import line..

Comment: Is there any @admin here? Couple of folks downvoted it without any comments.. I dont want to loose hard earned points for an issue that no one is able to solve yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue. Thanks to this link -> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications

Somehow PyCharm gets confused when we use the directory name as 'app' and application name also as 'app'.

Directory Structure:

```
flaskapp/
  app/
    __init__.py
    myviews.py
  run.py
```

Here are the contents :

## __init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)
import app.myviews
```

### myviews.py

```
from app import application

@application.route( '/' )
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

### run.py

```
from app import application
application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Now in the PyCharm config, configure the run.py as target file to be executed. Hope this helps someone in future as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to install flask in PyCharm as well as in Python by using
 `pip install flask` command .If you install only in Pycharm then it will show such type of error.

I have same problem this trick woks for me.

Comment: I really confused by `in PyCharm` vs `in Python` ^^